# Replace an onclick by a submit button

Tags: php, arrays, forms, radio-button, submit-button

I am looking for create a submit button, But I don't know how to get an answer ID and convert it in javascript variable.

My code:

```
<div id="<?php echo $question_ID?>">
    <form method="post">
        <p><?php echo $question ['question_content']; ?></p>
        <p>
    <?php 
    $poll_option_selection = "SELECT option_ID, option_content FROM poll_options WHERE question_ID='$question_ID'";
    $poll_option_result = mysqli_query ($connect,$poll_option_selection) ;
    foreach ($poll_option_result as $poll_option) { 
        $option_ID = $poll_option ['option_ID'] ;
        $option_content = $poll_option ['option_content'] ;
    ?>
    <input type="radio" name="option_selected" value ='<?php echo $option_ID ?>' onclick='getVote(this.value) ;' required /> 
    <?php echo $option_content ?>
    </br>
    <?php } ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: As for your main question: you need to generate `<select>` element.

Comment: Please, edit your question putting the code instead of the image.

Comment: Teresko, my form is a radio typre, not a select type :/

Comment: @AdouPro I just updated your question with the code you posted in an answer, but the next time remember to update your question using the EDIT button (_you can find it under the question tags_) and NOT in the answer section ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer after several test.

First. I put this the label "on submit=" on my form.

```html
<form onsubmit='getVote(question_ID);'>
```

After this, I create my function

```html
  <script>  function getVote(question_ID) {
   var option_ID = document.querySelector('input[id="option"]:checked').value; </script>
```

Thank you for everthing